# output all files on an FTP server in order of greatest to smallest

Tags: linux, ftp

our FTP server is close to full and I want to figure out what's taking up the most space - is there a way to write a script or use some software or something to list all files in order of size from greatest to smallest? It is a linux server. I have FTP access but no SSH access at the moment.

Comment: Do you only have access to the server via FTP? Or can you login to it? What kind of system is it? Windows? Linux? AIX? Solaris? HP-UX? OS/2?

Comment: I have FTP access. It is a Linux server. I do not have SSH access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your FTP client, run:

```
ls -alR
```

capture the output and parse it as you please.

Comment: I get a blank response. 500 unknown command

Comment: Then the FTP server doesn't support it. Easiest way is to get in touch with the admins of the server and just *ask* them for, say, the output of `df -k`.